# Change to A Relational DB With Reactive

Tags: jhipster

The current alpha version of reactive JHipster doesn't support relational DB yet although the current R2DBC already supports those majority relational DBs. For a generated reactive microservice with MongoDB, what changes do I need other than the DatabaseConfiguration class and anything related to MongoDB under the docker directory as well as the MongoDB dependency in gradle.build?

Comment: This is something that we're working on. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7608#issuecomment-569480384 for more information.

Comment: @MattRaible Thanks, Matt. I am looking for to the completion of Reactive. There were so many reactive presentations in the last SpringOne.